# How to get text from MS Project's XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, ms-project

I've an XML file that created in MS Project. It is like as that:

[image]

I want to get UID values in "Resource" Node. I try this:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string strFileName = "Sample.xml";
        xmlDoc.Load(strFileName);

        XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Project/Resources/Resource");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(xn["UID"].InnerText);
        }
```

However, *xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Project/Resources/Resource");* returns nothing. What is wrong?

Comment: Is the `XML` file loaded correctly? And I would suggest to use `LINQ to XML`.

Comment: Yes. There is no problem about this.

Comment: Resource doesn't have an InnerText.  UID does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add namespace:

```
var man = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
man.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/project");

XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ns:Project/ns:Resources/ns:Resource", man);
```

Also, you can do it as:

```
var xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ns:Project/ns:Resources/ns:Resource/ns:UID", man);

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xn.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MSPDI is not a pleasant XML format to work with. You may find the C# variant of [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) easier to work with to extract data. You'll find it on NuGet!

Comment: I've tried your MPXJ library Jon. It produces random errors, always. It shows different WBS and summary between importing and exporting.